# How does one get endnotes at the end of every chapter?

Tags: subdividing, endnotes

Is it possible to get endnotes at the end of every chapter? Presently I am using the [`endnotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/endnotes) package and it seems to only generate all the endnotes together at the point where I put `\theendnotes`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can also stick with `endnotes`. Each time you use `\theendnotes`, all endnotes that were stored previously will be put there. So just write `\theendnotes` at the end of each chapter.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
Testing.\endnote{First test.}
\theendnotes

\setcounter{endnote}{0}

\chapter{Next}
Again.\endnote{Second test.}
\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Farhat: If you want to stick with the endnotes package, here's a quote from `endnotes.sty`: "The user may want separate endnotes for each chapter, or a big block of them at the end of the whole document.  As it stands, either will work; you just say `\theendnotes` wherever you want the endnotes so far to be inserted.  However, you must add `\setcounter{endnote}{0}` after that if you want subsequent endnotes to start numbering at 1 again."

Comment: @lockstep: thanks, I updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 16):

The [`pagenote`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/pagenote.html) package allows for endnotes ("pagenotes") at the end of each chapter.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{pagenote}
\makepagenote

\renewcommand*{\notedivision}{\section*{\notesname\ to chapter~\thechapter}}
\renewcommand*{\pagenotesubhead}[2]{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{bla}

\section{blubb}

Some text.\pagenote{The first endnote.}

\printnotes*

\chapter{foo}

\section{bar}

Some text.\pagenote{The second endnote.}

\printnotes*

\end{document}
```