# How to renew \chapter command to include endnotes (i.e., \printnotes)

Tags: chapters, endnotes

I'm using the `pagenote` package to put my endnotes at the end of every chapter. For example, see the accepted answer for this question: [How does one get endnotes at the end of every chapter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9475/how-does-one-get-endnotes-at-the-end-of-every-chapter)

In short:

```
\chapter{First Chapter}
 some text
\printnotes*
```

How can I renew the `\chapter` command so that I don't have to include `\printnotes*` at the end of every chapter?

I don't want to make the `\printnotes*` command happen before the `\chapter` command because then I'll get notes before the first chapter (which doesn't make sense).

Comment: LaTeX doesn't know when a chapter ends, but only when a new one starts, which is not exactly the same thing, as you discovered.

Comment: @egreg That is what I'm trying to avoid. If I have to manually enter the `\printnotes` command at the end of every chapter, I know I'll forget it somewhere.

Comment: What if a chapter has no endnotes? What about the final chapter? What about a bibliography added with `biblatex` which emits `\chapter*`? And so on. I don't think that your book has so many chapters that checking for `\printnotes*` at their end is overwhelming. :)

Comment: @egreg You have a point there. I may have to reconsider what I want to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `\pretocmd` provided by the [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pagenote}
\makepagenote
\begin{document}

\chapter{Chap 1}

\pretocmd{\chapter}{\printnotes*}{}{}

\chapter{Chap 2}
\chapter{Chap 3}
\chapter{Chap 4}
\printnotes*

\end{document}
```

As you can see the command may be used after the initial `\chapter`.

**Edit #1**

As I've made the correction on the code above, another `\printnotes*` command is required at the end of the final chapter.

**Edit #2**

It might feel more convenient to automate the process in the preamble itself with the help of logic.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pagenote}
\makepagenote

\renewcommand*{\notedivision}{\section*{\notesname\ to chapter~\thechapter}}
\renewcommand*{\pagenotesubhead}[2]{}

\pretocmd{\chapter}{%
    \ifnum\value{chapter}>0\relax\printnotes*\fi%
}{}{}
%\pretocmd{\backmatter}{\printnotes*}{}{}
\AtEndDocument{\printnotes*}    

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chap 1}
\chapter{Chap 2}
\chapter{Chap 3}

\end{document}
```

In the presence of `backmatter` the line `\pretocmd{\backmatter}{\printnotes*}{}{}` can be uncommented while `\AtEndDocument` may be omitted.

Comment: `\AtEndDocument` is probably wrong if the book has some backmatter material.

Comment: It's actually meant to be commented out if `\backmatter` been used. Maybe its not very clear in the code.

Comment: I'd use `\ifnum\value{chapter}>0\relax\printnotes*\fi` as `\thechapter` may be not (completely) numerical.

Answer (score 0):

The solution given here works, if you are sure that you want to have all endnotes at the end of each chapter.  But what if you want to decide to revert to all endnotes at the end? And what if you also have some endnotes in a Preface, indicated as `\chapter*{Preface}` that appears before the `\mainmatter` ?

I've extended this solution to give me the choice, using an `etoolbox` toggle, 
`\newtoggle{chapternotes}`.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{chapternotes}
\toggletrue{chapternotes}
%\togglefalse{chapternotes}

\iftoggle{chapternotes}{%
    % using chapternotes
    \renewcommand{\notedivision}{\section*{\notesname\ to Chapter~\thechapter}}%
    \renewcommand{\pagenotesubhead}[2]{}%
%   \pretocmd{\chapter}{\printnotes*}{}{}%
    \pretocmd{\chapter}{%
        \ifnum\value{chapter}>0\relax\printnotes*\fi%
    }{}{}
    \pretocmd{\mainmatter}{\printnotes*}{}{}%   Notes in Preface
    \pretocmd{\backmatter}{\printnotes*}{}{}%
}{%
    % using notes at end of book
    \renewcommand{\notedivision}{\chapter*{\notesname}}
}
```

In my main file, I include another `\iftoggle` to decide whether to print the the Notes at the end,

```
\backmatter
% Endnotes, whether in chapters or all at the end
\iftoggle{chapternotes}{%
    \relax % using chapternotes
}{%
    % using notes at end of book
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Notes}
\printnotes
}
```

A related question, [change footnotes to endnotes, but allow some old footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399527/change-footnotes-to-endnotes-but-allow-some-old-footnotes), describes how to switch some footnotes to endnotes.