# How can I create a simple footnote to a document?

Tags: footnotes

I need to create footnotes that reference a place in the page footer or on the last page, where I can place the additional information.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  You can search this site for `\footnote` and get a wide variety of information on how LaTeX handles footnotes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a command for footnotes in most LaTeX document styles: `\footnote{Text that you want here}`.

[The Overleaf footnote help page](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Footnotes) will give you some good hints.

If you want endnotes, then you could use the package [`endnotes`](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/endnotes/endnotes.pdf). There is a good answer on how to do  it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56145/is-there-a-way-to-move-all-footnotes-to-the-end-of-the-document).

If you [need notes in the end of the chapter, the answer is given here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9475/how-does-one-get-endnotes-at-the-end-of-every-chapter).

In some styles you can use very fancy notes in the margin, or margin notes. [They work with the `\marginpar` command](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Margin_notes).